# Best way to add key-value pairs to a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value, populate

I am using a dictionary in C# to store some key-value pairs and had a question on the best way to populate the dictionary.

I need to do some other operations in order to find and add my key-value pairs to my dictionary. After those operations I may have found a key-value to add to the dictionary or I could have found nothing.

My question is how I should populate the dictionary?

- Should I use a function that returns a key-value pair if found and otherwise an empty one contained within a dictionary.Add(function()) call? I don't want to add an empty key-value pair to the dictionary, so I'm not sure how the return call for that function would work, or
- Should I pass the dictionary to the function and add to it if needed? Like:

  ```
  function(dictionary) 
  {
      if (pair found)
      {
          dictionary.add(pair)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why not use the native Dictionary<TKey, TValue>?  It already manages storage, has a ContainsKey method for checking key existence, and you can use LINQ on it to return KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entries?

Comment: i am looking for the best way to populate a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> object. In order to populate it, i need to perform some other operations to come up with objects to place in the dict. Therefore, should i push those operations to a method and have it return a keyvalue pair to then add to the dic? or should i pass the newly created dict and pass it to the function to add to it if any values are found?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do with this method, and whether it should have that ability.  From my understanding, I would just push in the dictionary, and let the method do its work.  It will be the easiest to implement.

Comment: use the second option - pass the dictionary to your method. I don't know of a value which can be passed to the dictionary's add method which will result in no addition.

Comment: Your question leaves a lot of room for assumptions, so there's no good way to answer it. From what I've read, you should be using something more like the second approach (adding something to the dictionary only if a match is found), but I still think we could clean this up a good bit more if you provide more details (like the code you're working with).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not sure what you ask here, but here is how I handle dictionary to either add or update a value based on a key:

```
string key = "some key here";
string value = "your value";
if (myDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    myDict[key] = value;
}
else
{
    myDict.Add(key, value);
}
```

You can wrap this in a method if you like:

```
void AddOrUpdate(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key, string value)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict[key] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }
}

//usage:
AddOrUpdate(myDict, "some key here", "your value");
```

You can also use the `TryGetValue` method but can't see any obvious advantage in this.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but dict[key]=value either adds or updates the value (the set calls "private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)").

Comment: @user276648 I was the one missing big chuck of sense, you're totally right! I used to work with dictionaries back in classic ASP and guess the syntax just stuck. Feel free to post new answer with that simple way so others will get to know the setter.

Answer (score 3):

your pseudo code is right.

```
public void Process( bool add, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary )
{
   if( add ) dictionary.Add( "added", "value" );
}
```

you could also use an extension method:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void AddIfNotNull(this Dictionary<string,object> target, string key, object value )
    {
        if( value != null )
            target.Add( key, value );
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>( );

        dictionary.AddIfNotNull( "not-added",    null );
        dictionary.AddIfNotNull( "added",       "true" );

        foreach( var item in dictionary )
            Console.WriteLine( item.Key );

        Console.Read( );
    }

}
```